# How can i obtain GPS location in Android Webkit or Opera Mobile 10

Tags: android, gps, opera, opera-mobile

Well the question is in the title.

**How can i obtain GPS location on a mobile device in Android Webkit or/and Opera Mobile 10?**

So in iPhone Safari this is doable. How about those 2 browsers? I looked for such functionalities and found nothing. Is that doable via javascript as well?

Answer (score 3):

see http://html5demos.com/geo. Relevant bit of JS for HTML5 location:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback);
} else {
  error('not supported');
}
```

yep, it's that easy.

Comment: may I ask you to have a look at an opera-mobile related question here : tinyurl.com/ovglq92 ?